# Maximum distance of the numbers of players around a table

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose that a team of $ n $ players (numbered from 1 to $ n $)  sit around a circular table and there are their numbers on their T-shirts.

Let $ a_1,a_2,..., a_n $ be the sequence of numbers around the table and so $ a_n $ sits beside $ a_1$.
What is the maximum value of $|a_1-a_n|+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1 }|a_{k+1}-a_k|$?

As we checked the maximum value is equal to $ n^2/2$ for even $ n $ but we can not prove it. Could you help us?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I just verified this conjecture up to n = 22 by solving for the maximum as a Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP) problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n$ even let $\{b_{2i-1}, b_{2i}\} = \{a_{2i-1}, a_{2i}\}$ with $b_{2i-1} < b_{2i}$.  Then $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\} = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} |a_{2i-1} - a_{2i}| 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n/2} (b_{2i} - b_{2i-1}) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} b_{2i} - \sum_{i=0}^{n/2} b_{2i-1} \\
&\leq \sum_{i=0}^{n/2} (n/2+i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} i = n^2/4,
\end{align*}
$$
by taking the even-indexed $b_i$ to be as large as possible and the odd-indexed $b_i$ to be as small as possible.  Similarly,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} |a_{2i} - a_{2i+1}| \leq n^2/4,
$$
with indices taken mod $n$.  Summing these inequalities gives the upper bound, and you can get a matching lower bound by using the larger and smaller halves of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ in the odd- and even-indexed positions respectively.

Comment: An equivalent, maybe clearer definition: $b_{2i-1}=\min(a_{2i-1},a_{2i})$, $b_{2i}=\max(a_{2i-1},a_{2i})$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your nice solution!